# How to get object from an drag drop event with angular cdk

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I'm having trouble getting an object from a drag and drop event. I can get the object (Course) in the console log but I want to use it as an object and that's where I'm stuck.

```
board: Board = new Board('testBoard',[
  new Column('Column 1', [
    new Course("programmeren II", 6, 1, 0, null, ''),
    new Course("programmeren III", 6, 1, 0, null, ''),
    new Course("Internet of Things I", 6, 1, 0, null, ''),
    new Course("Elektronische Netwerken", 6, 1, 0, null, ''),
  ])
]);


drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Course[]>) {
 if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
  moveItemInArray(event.container.data, ....);
 } else {
  if (this.checkForCourseDependencies(event)) {....}
 }
}
```

and the checkForCourseDependencies function where I want to get the object that was dragged and dropped

```
private checkForCourseDependencies(event) {
  console.log(event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex]);
  this.x = event.target as Course;
  console.log(this.x);
  return false;
}
```

the HTML-code if this is usefull:

```
<div class="board">
  <div class="board-title"><p>{{board.name}}</p></div>
  <div class="board-body">
    <div class="board-columns" cdkDropListGroup>
      <div class="board-column" *ngFor="let column of board.columns">
        <div class="board-column-title">
          {{column.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="trajectory-container" cdkDropList id="list-2" cdkDropListConnectedTo="list-1"
             [cdkDropListData]="column.courses"
             (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
          <div class="trajectory" *ngFor="let item of column.courses" cdkDrag>
            {{item.name}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can view the wanted data from the first console log but the second one throws an error as shown in the added image.

[image]

Comment: you can see the output of the console if you click the "enter image description here" link. (Sorry I forgot to edit the text of the link), added the html code

Comment: I posted another edit with more code, the column contains courses. I can drag courses from a column (in another component) to this column but I want to use the dragged course as an object in the checkForCourseDependencies function